# Angular : How to get constant values in the component after setting them?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've a constant array of orders like this in **constants.ts** file

```
       export const ORDERS = [
           {
            'id': 'PROCESSING',
            'displayName': null
           },
           {
            'id': 'SHIPPED',
            'displayName': null
           }
        ];
```

Here in my component I'm setting the value of 'displayName'

```
import { ORDERS } from './constants';
-----------------
--------------
setOrders() {
        ORDERS.forEach((order: any) => {

        if(order.id === 'PROCESSING') {
           order.displayName = 'Processing';
        }

        if(order.id === 'SHIPPED') {
           order.displayName = 'Shipped';
        }

     });
    }
```

But here when I try to get values of 'displayName' in another funtion it return null, but in the object order I can see the value of 'displayName'

```
getOrders() {
        ORDERS.forEach((order: any) => {
                console.log(order); // displayName exists in the object
                console.log(order.displayName); // But here null
        });
    }
```

Both functions are in a same component. Please help me how to resolve this thanks.

**Update : Full implementation**

```
getTimePeriod() {
        return Promise.resolve((() => {

            this.orderService.getTimePeriod()
                .subscribe(
                    (data) => {
                        this.orderStatusList = data.configParameters;
                        this.orderStatusList.forEach(
                            (s: any) => {
                                if (s.status === 'PROCESSING') { this.setOrders(s.status, s.name); }

                                if (s.status === 'SHIPPED') { this.setOrders((s.status, s.name); }
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    error => {
                        this.errorMessage = this.orderService.handleError(error);
                    }
                );
                })());
    }

    setOrders(status, name) {
        ORDERS.forEach((order: any) => {
            if (order.id === status) {
                order.displayName = name;
            }
        });
    }

     getOrders() {
        return Promise.resolve((() => {

        ORDERS.forEach((order: any) => {
            const { displayName } = order;

            console.log(order); // displayName exists in order
            console.log(displayName); // Null

            this.orderService.getOrdersByDisplayName(buildQuery(null, displayName, null, null))
                .subscribe(
                    (data) => {
                        this.ordersWidgetInfo.push({

                            ...order,
                            ...data,
                            number: data.orders && data.orders.length,
                        });
                    },
                    error => {
                        console.log(`error for ${orderType} : ${error}`);
                    }
                );
        }
        );
        })());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way a bug like this would occur (other than the code being wrong) is with an invalid order of execution.

However, after trying your code, it seems to works just fine. [See example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ntbk9gd).

This leads me to conclude that your problem is most likely that `getOrders` is being invoked before `setOrders`, thus the null values. To fix this, make sure you are calling `setOrders` before you call `getOrders`.

Comment: This is bizzare. Although I'm returning promise and executing methods like this 
`this.setOrders().then(() => {this.getOrders()});`

Comment: Is there anywhere else in your code that these two methods are being called?

Comment: No just inside `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Show your entire implementation of `setOrders`. I assume the issue is inside there given all the information so far.

Comment: In your code, your `getTimePeriod` method is where `setOrders` is called. It only calls `setOrders` after it gets a response from the HTTP request. Later in your code, you have the `getOrders` which reads the values from the `ORDERS` constant, but it does this without any care about the `getTimePeriod` function. In other words, your `getOrders` is independent of the `getTimePeriod`/`setOrders`, and thus will not wait for them to complete before it tries to read the values. Why did you even out promises in those methods if you aren't using them?

Comment: Ohh I see and I used promise so inside `ngOnInit()` method I can execute fucntion sequentially. Can you please guide me how to resolve this ?

Comment: You must call `resolve` of the promise *after* your HTTP response is returned and you set the values of the `ORDERS` constant. Change your code from `return Promise.resolve(() =>` to `return new Promise(resolve =>`, and after you modify the values, you need to call `resolve()`. This way, when the promise is resolved for `getOrders`, the values you read should not be null anymore. Do you understand?

Comment: Explained again in a different way: you are returning a promise from your `getTimePeriod` method, however the promise is already resolved (you do `return Promise.resolve(() =>`). What you need to do is return an unresolved promise (`return new Promise(resolve =>`), and then later in your logic after the HTTP response is received and you do whatever logic you want, THEN and only then do you call `resolve()`. That way, whatever other code is listening for the resolved promise, it will wait until the point at which `resolve()` is invoked.

Comment: like this : 
`retrieveDataPromise(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.getTimePeriod();
            resolve();
        })
    }`

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/vdhjrxew/ - As you see, this is how you should deal with promises. Read the comments and understand what I'm doing there, and then implement something similar in your own code to make sure that the `getOrders` logic only happens *after* the `getTimePeriod` logic has received the HTTP response.

Comment: I've done everything as you mentioned but no luck :/

Comment: You have not, otherwise it would work. Show your entire code.